# SSMS intermittently executes my highlighted script against the wrong database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

On SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a script that explicitly begins with

```
USE MyDatabase;
```

and it never ever switches to any other database;
When I execute the whole script, it runs against the correct database, as I have specified in the first line.

If, however, after I have ran the whole script, I highlight and run a part of it, SSMS intermittently runs it against another database.

This is potentially very dangerous, and it never happened to me with previous versions of SQL Server!
How can I avoid this dangerous bug?

Comment: Might this happen after your spid has been killed and it has to reconnect or does it happen when this definitely is not the case?

Comment: @Martin: I reproduced it on my workstation. I think my connection could not be killed - nobody can access my workstation except me, and I did not kill it.

Comment: @Alex I don't think Martin meant exclusively the `KILL` command but any connection severing event.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sounds like [this Connect bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/634777/ssms-auto-reconnects-after-raiserror-in-script) that occurs if you have a RAISERROR or your SSMS session gets otherwise disconnected (this can be due to flaky network and you may not notice that it happened). It is a dangerous bug and while the Connect item doesn't state so explicitly, I suggest you apply [SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26727) to your workstation, as I've heard that it is fixed there.

Comment: I do have RAISERROR in my script. Thank you Aaron!

Comment: No problem Alex, hope the issue is in fact fixed in the service pack. It's still an issue in Denali CTP3.

Answer (score 1):

I also prefer to fully qualify my tables (database.schema.table) in all queries rather than rely on a use statement.

Comment: The downside to this is that (a) it makes the queries harder to read and (b) makes them less portable (consider a big honking reporting query you're developing in QA, which has a different database name than test, which has a different name than staging, and a different name than production - yes you can use synonyms here to minimize this shift, but that is a different waxball too).

Comment: On the same test server I have several copies of production db, for different kinds of testing. Fully qualifying names would make our testing inconvenient.